# Why doesn't python phonenumbers library work in this case?

Tags: python, libphonenumber

It seems like '5187621769' should be a very easy number for the phonenumbers library to parse. It's 10 digits with a US area code. But...no luck.

**Setup:**

```
import phonenumbers
number = '5187621769'
```

**Method 1:**

```
parsed = phonenumbers.parse(number)
```

This throws an error.

**Method 2:**

```
parsed = phonenumbers.parse("+" + number)
```

Gives country code = 51, which is not US.

I know I can do:

```
parsed = phonenumbers.parse(number,region="US")
```

But I don't always know the number will be US (this is just one case where I discovered I wasn't getting desired behavior). Is there an option or formatting trick I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: How is it supposed to know it is a USA phone number if you don't specify a region and don't use an international dialling code?

Comment: I think it is supposed to be able to guess that 10 digits by themselves constitute a phone number.

Comment: What does "parsed = phonenumbers.parse("518-762-1769")" produce?

Comment: `+51` is a perfectly legitimate international dialling code (it's Peru's); how is it supposed to know that isn't what you mean?

Comment: @ojblass `NumberParseException: (0) Missing or invalid default region.`

Answer (score 6):

It would a very easy number if phonenumbers was an US only library. You are missing the "+1" a.k.a. country code. If you would like to assume that numbers that phonenumbers can't parse are US numbers you could do something like:

```
try:
    parsed = phonenumbers.parse(number)
except phonenumbers.NumberParseException as npe:
    parsed = phonenumbers.parse('+1{}'.format(number))
```

Answer (score 6):

You should simply use:

```
parsed = phonenumbers.parse(number, 'US')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write Country Code with Phone Number while searching for Phone Number details.

Moreover, Here is an API (a wrapper of libphonenumber) for Phone Numbers:

http://blog.ones-app.com/ones-phone-number-api/

Comment: I believe, if we put +1, +91, +22 codes before numbers that API may not responsed, there are cases where we have numbers like : +1 - 2345 - 2333, API will not work for these cases I believe.

Comment: It works in that case as well because the Wrapper API ignores all characters.

Comment: helpful , I will try and let the results publish.

Comment: Please note that I am taking about this wrapper http://blog.ones-app.com/ones-phone-number-api/

Comment: You can download this wrapper from Github (https://github.com/azharkhn/libphonenumber-api) and run on own server or host

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code and this one works.

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder

phone_number = "+91 1234567890" 

parsed_number = phonenumbers.parse(phone_number)

location = geocoder.description_for_number(parsed_number, "en")

print(f"The location of the phone number {phone_number} is: {location}")
```

The +91 is used in india as im from india, you can customize it according the country you live.